# Saving monitor settings?

Tags: hardware, multiple-monitors, thinkpad, settings, lenovo

Is there a way to save my monitor settings? I have an external monitor at work, but each morning i have to plug it in, rearrange the windows from being side by side to being on top of each other. Can I just save this?

Answer (score 17):

Long story short (that is: do what [Nicolas Bernaerts](http://www.bernaerts-nicolas.fr/linux/74-ubuntu/309-ubuntu-dual-display-monitor-position-lost) suggests, but I spare you the details): monitors configuration is actually saved in `~/.config/monitors.xml`, but it's not applied at startup/login.

The steps to overcome this are:

Log in with the wrong monitors configuration.

Remove current monitor configuration:

```
cd .config
mv monitors.xml{,.bak}
```

Use the *Displays* application to arrange the monitors as you wish (I have one side monitor rotated counterclockwise).
[image: arrange your monitors as you wish]

Once you press *Apply*, a new `monitors.xml` is created.

Now, download and make executable the script and the launcher that force the monitor configuration based on the newly created config file:

```
$ sudo wget -O /usr/local/sbin/update-monitor-position https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NicolasBernaerts/ubuntu-scripts/master/ubuntugnome/update-monitor-position
$ sudo chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/update-monitor-position
$ sudo wget -O /usr/share/applications/update-monitor-position.desktop https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NicolasBernaerts/ubuntu-scripts/master/ubuntugnome/update-monitor-position.desktop
$ sudo chmod +x /usr/share/applications/update-monitor-position.desktop
```

At this point, the monitors' configuration can be fixed by launching the *update monitor position* application.

If you want this to be automatic, simply add a startup application, with the following entries:

- Name: `Update Monitors Position`
- Command: `update-monitor-position 5`
- Comment: `Force monitors position 5 seconds after login`

[image]

Comment: Great, this helped. Thanks! Is there a bug report for this?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/1625600

Comment: I think this is the best answer. I updated the script to support multiple profiles: https://gist.github.com/relet/66a965cdf728e5278fbf52c9d1433be0 - just copy your monitors.xml to e.g. monitors-office.xml if you want to run "update-monitor-position office"

Comment: vanvugt: "Actually, let's use bug 1292398 since that's the one most users are finding." https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1292398

Comment: doesnt work for popos :(

Comment: Isn't there asimpler way to tell the xrandr: "dude, I changed monitor.xml (copied my saved copy into place), please update accordingly" ?

Comment: I had a similar issue - each time the screen blanked (default setting is after 5 minutes idle, I think - not sleep/standby, but just blank for powersave), my monitor/display settings would be wrong when activating the machine again. Removing monitors.xml and recreating it with the display settings, solved the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Configuration for all your monitors - hot-plugged or not - *should* be stored in `$HOME/.config/monitors.xml` by the `xrandr` plugin for `gnome-settings-daemon`, which is what actually applies the configuration you make in the Monitors capplet.

Since it seems that this isn't working properly for everyone, there's clearly a bug somewhere.  Urgh.

Comment: Yeah, and as maco says, if i shut off the computer and boot it back up, it remembers, just not when it's already on.

Answer (score 4):

First three steps to connect your external monitor the way you want and 4th is to save the settings.

1. Connect your external monitor and check its supported resolution:

   ```
   xrandr -q
   ```
2. Give the following command (This will disable your laptop monitor):

   ```
   xrandr --output LVDS1 --off --output TV1 --off --output VGA1 --mode 1280x1024 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal
   ```
3. If you want both laptop and external enabled:

   ```
   xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode yyyyXzzzz --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output TV1 --off --output VGA1 --mode 1280x1024 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal
   ```

   (yyyyXzzzz - your laptop resolution.)

   The above configuration will clone your screen. Play with "`--right-of` / `--left-of`" option if you want.
4. If you need this settings while login, add the checks in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/45custom_xrandr-settings` (You might need to create one).

   ```
   xrandr |grep VGA1 | grep " connected " | if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then xrandr --output LVDS1 --off --output TV1 --off --output VGA1 --mode 1280x1024 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal  #Change the way u need ; fi
   ```

Answer (score 4):

At office, I have 3 monitors on my laptop, and 2 at home. Two of office monitors are set vertical, while other monitors are at normal orientation.

A. monitors.xml is in ~/.config.

1. Delete it
2. Set the display at office setup
3. Rename just created "monitors.xml" to "monitors-office.xml".

B. Get shell script, "update-monitor-position".

1. Change the "MONITOR_XML" definition, "monitors.xml" to
   "monitors-office.xml".
2. Save it as "update-monitor-position-office", in executable path (/usr/local/sbin/).
3. Touch the permission -> executable by "Me".

C. Get desktop shortcut, "update-monitor-position.desktop"

1. Change "Exec" definition, "update-monitor-position" to
   "update-monitor-position-office".
2. Save it as "update-monitor-position-office.desktop"
3. Touch the permission -> executable by "Me".

update-monitor-position-office.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=update-monitor-position-office
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=Office Monitors Position
Name=Office Monitors Position
Comment[en_US]=Force monitors position from monitor-office.xml
Comment=Force monitors position from monitor-office.xml
Icon=display
```

Shell script, update-monitor-position-office

```
#!/bin/bash
# -------------------------------------------------
#  Get monitors configuration from monitor.xml and apply it for current user session.
#  In case of multiple definitions in monitor.xml only first one is used.
#
#  See http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/309-ubuntu-dual-display-monitor-position-lost
#  for instructions
#
#  Parameters :
#    $1 : waiting time in sec. before forcing configuration (optional)
#
#  Revision history :
#    19/04/2014, V1.0 - Creation by N. Bernaerts
#    10/07/2014, V1.1 - Wait 5 seconds for X to fully initialize
#    01/09/2014, V1.2 - Correct NULL file bug (thanks to Ivan Harmady) and handle rotation
#    07/10/2014, V1.3 - Add monitors size and rate handling (idea from jescalante)
#    08/10/2014, V1.4 - Handle primary display parameter
#    08/12/2014, V1.5 - Waiting time in seconds becomes a parameter
# -------------------------------------------------

# monitor.xml path
MONITOR_XML="$HOME/.config/monitors-office.xml"

# get number of declared monitors
NUM=$(xmllint --xpath 'count(//monitors/configuration['1']/output)' $MONITOR_XML)

# loop thru declared monitors to create the command line parameters
for (( i=1; i<=$NUM; i++)); do
  # get attributes of current monitor (name and x & y positions)
  NAME=$(xmllint --xpath 'string(//monitors/configuration['1']/output['$i']/@name)' $MONITOR_XML 2>/dev/null)
  POS_X=$(xmllint --xpath '//monitors/configuration['1']/output['$i']/x/text()' $MONITOR_XML 2>/dev/null)
  POS_Y=$(xmllint --xpath '//monitors/configuration['1']/output['$i']/y/text()' $MONITOR_XML 2>/dev/null)
  ROTATE=$(xmllint --xpath '//monitors/configuration['1']/output['$i']/rotation/text()' $MONITOR_XML 2>/dev/null)
  WIDTH=$(xmllint --xpath '//monitors/configuration['1']/output['$i']/width/text()' $MONITOR_XML 2>/dev/null)
  HEIGHT=$(xmllint --xpath '//monitors/configuration['1']/output['$i']/height/text()' $MONITOR_XML 2>/dev/null)
  RATE=$(xmllint --xpath '//monitors/configuration['1']/output['$i']/rate/text()' $MONITOR_XML 2>/dev/null)
  PRIMARY=$(xmllint --xpath '//monitors/configuration['1']/output['$i']/primary/text()' $MONITOR_XML 2>/dev/null)

  # if position is defined for current monitor, add its position and orientation to command line parameters
  [ -n "$POS_X" ] && PARAM_ARR=("${PARAM_ARR[@]}" "--output" "$NAME" "--pos" "${POS_X}x${POS_Y}" "--fbmm" "${WIDTH}x${HEIGHT}" "--rate" "$RATE" "--rotate" "$ROTATE")

  # if monitor is defined as primary, adds it to command line parameters
  [ "$PRIMARY" = "yes" ] && PARAM_ARR=("${PARAM_ARR[@]}" "--primary")
done

# if needed, wait for some seconds (for X to finish initialisation)
[ -n "$1" ] && sleep $1

# position all monitors
xrandr "${PARAM_ARR[@]}"
```

Comment: Hey @jey, you answered this in January 2018. (while Nicolas script [is 4 years old...](https://github.com/NicolasBernaerts/ubuntu-scripts/tree/master/ubuntugnome)). May I assume this is still working under a recent Ubuntu 16.x / 18.x? – And: do you have any assumption, if it would work under Ubuntu-**MATE** as well? (I do see said monitors.xml on my system...)

Comment: Frank, mine says "16.04.5 LTS". One point, after "dist-upgrade", I had to go through the process, and then reboot. The "System Settings -> Displays" works funny on my system. I am not in the mode to try 18.x. Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to run this script from a terminal since I open one first after login.

First login with the bad configuration - monitors not placed correctly:

```
cd ~/.config
mv ~/.config/monitors.xml{,.bak}
```

Now set your monitors with system settings to create a new `~/.config/monitors.xml` file with proper settings.

Copy Nicolas Bernaerts's fixed script from my repo: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alextomko/monitors/master/monitors and put it in a path to run from terminal.

```
$ ls -l ~/bin
# if you don't have this directory then create it - do not be logged in as root here.

$ mkdir /home/$USER/bin

$ echo $PATH
# should show /home/username/bin if the dir existed or if you had to create.

$ wget -P ~/bin https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alextomko/monitors/master/monitors
$ chmod +x ~/bin/monitors

# Log out, lock, reboot or whatever it takes to make monitor settings lost for you and run the script.
$ monitors
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for pointing me at the  `~/.config/monitors.xml`  file.

I found that there was one created at the time I specified the layout I wanted, and also some kind of back-up,  `monitors.xml~`  which differed in just the characteristic I wanted to change.

If I simply eliminated this backup file, I found that my newly-created one took effect the next time I restarted my machine. No need to download any script.

I guess, if there had been a bug, it has since been fixed.

Also guessing, I'm surmising the backup file got re-instated somehow, but with it gone, the primary file remains the only file in effect.

This worked both on a setup running Ubu 16.04 and one running 19.10

Again, thanks for pointing me at the file.

Comment: Also worked on my Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: But only works 1-2 times

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 12.04 remembers hot-plugged monitor settings. But they are only applied when you reopen the System configuration > Displays applet. This is the case for me, at least, and this is definitively a bug.

Answer (score 1):

jay's answer almost worked for me, but I needed to do a couple extra steps. I'd make this a comment on his answer but I don't have the reputation.

In the file update-monitor-position-office:

1. My version of bash (4.3.48) complained about the lack of a space following "i++" on line 28.
2. My version of xrandr (1.5) did not recognize the "--fbmm" option on line 40. I had to change this to "--mode". This was hard to diagnose because xrandr did not actually give me an error, it just executed the command without doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to save configurations on hot-plugged monitors.  If you plug in before boot, GNOME should remember the configuration on each boot on a per-device basis (ie, connecting to your monitor at work versus the one at home).

Comment: Damn, ok. Is there a third party application than can do this? I know Mac OS X does this, and Windows 7 (from what I've tried with the little experience I have with W7).

Comment: The GNOME monitor configuration should save this information for hotplugged monitors, too.  It does for me.

Comment: RAOF: weird, since discussion on the ubuntu-devel mailing list earlier this week said it doesn't.

Comment: the configuration is actually saved in `~/.config/monitors.xml`, but it is not applied at startup

Answer (score 0):

Note that in Ubuntu 18.04, the monitors.xml layout seems to be different, so some of the xpath queries don't work anymore. I adapted the shell script posted by @jay to work accordingly:

```
#!/bin/bash
# -------------------------------------------------
#  Get monitors configuration from monitor.xml and apply it for current user session.
#  In case of multiple definitions in monitor.xml only first one is used.
#
#  See http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/309-ubuntu-dual-display-monitor-position-lost
#  for instructions
#
#  Parameters :
#    $1 : waiting time in sec. before forcing configuration (optional)
#
#  Revision history :
#    19/04/2014, V1.0 - Creation by N. Bernaerts
#    10/07/2014, V1.1 - Wait 5 seconds for X to fully initialize
#    01/09/2014, V1.2 - Correct NULL file bug (thanks to Ivan Harmady) and handle rotation
#    07/10/2014, V1.3 - Add monitors size and rate handling (idea from jescalante)
#    08/10/2014, V1.4 - Handle primary display parameter
#    08/12/2014, V1.5 - Waiting time in seconds becomes a parameter
#    06/17/2020, V1.6 - Adapted to new monitors version = 2 (see https://askubuntu.com/a/993592/93077)
# -------------------------------------------------

# monitor.xml path
MONITOR_XML="$HOME/.config/monitors-office.xml"

# get number of declared monitors
NUM=$(xmllint --xpath 'count(//monitors/configuration['1']/logicalmonitor)' $MONITOR_XML)
# loop thru declared monitors to create the command line parameters
for (( i=1; i<=$NUM; i++)); do
  # get attributes of current monitor (name and x & y positions)
  NAME=$(xmllint --xpath 'string(//monitors/configuration['1']/logicalmonitor['$i']//connector/text())' $MONITOR_XML 2>/dev/null)
  POS_X=$(xmllint --xpath '//monitors/configuration['1']/logicalmonitor['$i']/x/text()' $MONITOR_XML 2>/dev/null)
  POS_Y=$(xmllint --xpath '//monitors/configuration['1']/logicalmonitor['$i']/y/text()' $MONITOR_XML 2>/dev/null)
  #ROTATE=$(xmllint --xpath '//monitors/configuration['1']/logicalmonitor['$i']/rotation/text()' $MONITOR_XML 2>/dev/null)
  WIDTH=$(xmllint --xpath '//monitors/configuration['1']/logicalmonitor['$i']//width/text()' $MONITOR_XML 2>/dev/null)
  HEIGHT=$(xmllint --xpath '//monitors/configuration['1']/logicalmonitor['$i']//height/text()' $MONITOR_XML 2>/dev/null)
  RATE=$(xmllint --xpath '//monitors/configuration['1']/logicalmonitor['$i']//rate/text()' $MONITOR_XML 2>/dev/null)
  PRIMARY=$(xmllint --xpath '//monitors/configuration['1']/logicalmonitor['$i']/primary/text()' $MONITOR_XML 2>/dev/null)
  # if position is defined for current monitor, add its position and orientation to command line parameters
  [ -n "$POS_X" ] && PARAM_ARR=("${PARAM_ARR[@]}" "--output" "$NAME" "--pos" "${POS_X}x${POS_Y}" "--fbmm" "${WIDTH}x${HEIGHT}" "--rate" "$RATE" "--rotate" "normal")
  # if monitor is defined as primary, adds it to command line parameters
  [ "$PRIMARY" = "yes" ] && PARAM_ARR=("${PARAM_ARR[@]}" "--primary")
done
# if needed, wait for some seconds (for X to finish initialisation)
[ -n "$1" ] && sleep $1

# position all monitors
xrandr "${PARAM_ARR[@]}"
```