# where are monitor settings for jammy?

Tags: drivers, login, display-resolution, hardware, monitor

I've looked in `~/.config/` but see no monitor [settings](https://askubuntu.com/a/6238/847449).

[image: resolution]

Just looking to change the resolution as it's quite squished after using `loginctl` to logout a user.

Comment: Are you running Xorg or Wayland sessions? If the former, `monitors.xml` will indeed be in `~/.config` but if you're using Wayland, it's elsewhere.

Comment: must be Wayland @popey --thanks for the info.  I'll confirm and will lookup how to change that.  I just want to reset them, or probe the monitor for available resolutions.  Along those lines.  I think that not all resolutions are being listed for some reason.

Comment: Installed to "bare metal" @Nmath and see also https://askubuntu.com/q/1460354/847449 (asking explicitly how to detect the settings).  In a nutshell, the display resolution changed.  The new options are rather limited.  Probably rebooting will fix it, but, if so, why and how?  Surely there's a way to probe or detect possible resolutions.